Benchmark function is ignored
My project structure:
project_root 
├── benches 
│   └── my_benchmark.rs
The my_benchmark.rs content:
use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

fn factorial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    (1..=n).product()
}

fn my_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    c.bench_function("factorial 20", |b| b.iter(|| factorial(20)));
}

criterion_group!(benches, my_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);

However, once I run the cargo bench I get this output:
Finished `bench` profile [optimized] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running unittests src/main.rs (target/release/deps/fwaas-cbcff0a631d9e180)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running benches/my_benchmark.rs (target/release/deps/my_benchmark-eddc0eabec0786a7)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

So, it seems like the actual benchmark gets ignored.
target/ dir content looks like this:
ls target/
CACHEDIR.TAG  release  tmp

Used criterion in my dependencies:
[dev-dependencies]
criterion = "0.5"

Alongside cargo version:
cargo 1.82.0


Check step 1: https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/getting_started.html#step-1---add-dependency-to-cargotoml
